# Insert captured data from html form in mysql in all caps

Tags: mysql

is there a way that i can insert entered data from the html form in mysql table all in caps so that when my table is displayed it is all in the same format? For example how can i re-write this statement to insert data in all caps.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `area`(name, hub, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$areaname',(SELECT `name` from hub WHERE name = '$hub'),
        (SELECT `id` from hub WHERE name = '$hub'))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [UPPER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

```
INSERT INTO `area`(name, hub, fk_hub_id) VALUES (UPPER('$areaname',(SELECT UPPER(`name`) from hub WHERE name = UPPER('$hub')), (SELECT `id` from hub WHERE name = UPPER('$hub')))
```